# Why is the Prolog ',' operator right associative, while it is processed from left to right

Tags: prolog

In prolog the ',' operator is typed as xfy, so right associative, while a series of terms separated by commas will be processed left to right. Why then is the operator right associative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When executing a conjunction such as `write(a),write(b),write(c),write(d)`
in Prolog, there are really two steps involved:

1. turning the textual representation into a tree structure
2. traversing and interpreting the tree structure

Operator associativity in Prolog only affects (1).  So, depending on the
associativity of the comma (and any parentheses you may have), you get
different trees:

```
op(1000,xfy,',')     op(1000,yfx,',')
a,b,c,d.             a,b,c,d.                (a,b),(c,d).

  ,                        ,                      ,
 / \                      / \                   /   \
a   ,                    ,   d                 ,     ,
   / \                  / \                   / \   / \
  b   ,                ,   c                 a   b  c  d
     / \              / \
    c   d            a   b
```

The interpretation of the comma-tree structure in step (2) always proceeds
depth-first, left-to-right.  This is built in and cannot be changed.
And since all parse trees have the same left-to-right order of their leaf
nodes, the order of subgoal execution is always a,b,c,d.  The semantics are
not affected by operator associativity and parenthesizing.

Comment: In which Prologs can you change the associativity of the comma? SWI-Prolog and GNU-Prolog and seemingly SICStus Prolog seem to not allow this.

Comment: [ECLiPSe](https://eclipseclp.org) allows it on a per-module basis. Unless you use ISO mode, where it is forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a terminological nuance. If we query SWI-Prolog the relevant details

```
?- current_op(P,A,(,)).
P = 1000,
A = xfy.

?- write_canonical((a,b,c)).
','(a,','(b,c))
```

we are confirmed that 'right associative' is just an (arguable?) linguistic description of the proper expression structure, that allows us to visit the term with a simple left recursion.

The logical reading is clearly appropriate: for `a,b,c` to be true, we need that `a` be true *and* `b,c` be true.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is good. Just to point out that you seem to be misunderstanding what "right associativity" means in this context. Taking the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity), and reading there, it says (quoting out of context so make sure to read the linked article):

> right-associative (meaning the operations are grouped from the right)

and this is *exactly* what you see in your example. The example in the intro with `~` is, again quoting:

> Consider the expression `a ~ b ~ c`. If the operator `~` has left associativity, this expression would be interpreted as `(a ~ b) ~ c`. If the operator has right associativity, the expression would be interpreted as `a ~ (b ~ c)`.

and again this is exactly what we see.

Comment: Nice! Hadn't thought to lookup in Wikipedia, such a detailed explanation... but note that `Addition and multiplication` in Prolog are actually declared as `yfx`, because the ambiguous `yfy` (both left and right associative) is disallowed.

Comment: @CapelliC From the same article again ;-) "In order to reflect normal usage, addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division operators are usually left-associative, while for an exponentiation operator (if present) and Knuth's up-arrow operators there is no general agreement." and yes it would be crazy if reading terms was non-deterministic